# interactive pdf on the iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, ios5

I have been looking for a way to present an interactive pdf file (created by in-design) on
the iPhone. I read a bunch of questions here but none says how to do it. The pdf file contain the text and in the middle it contains a 3d module, but when I present it on the iPhone it shows only the text and an empty white box where the module should appear.

Is it even possible to do it?
I'll be glad for any assistant on this subject or even where to look.

Thanks in advance,
Shahar.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's PDF parser does not support 3D stuff. You're better of implementing the 3D part yourself and just adding that as a UIView on top of the PDF. There are several PDF frameworks that help with that (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801358/pdf-parsing-library-for-ios)

Another alternative might be licensing Adobe's iOS rendering engine. But I doubt that they already added 3D support (or that they will be). Also, from what my sources tell me, pricing is rather high and apparently the framework not very developer friendly. (But I haven't used it myself)